# iText 7 for .NET Ignores and Resets Text Alignment if a Field is Marked as Multi-line

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7

I'm implementing PDF creation using iText 7 for .NET, upgrading from iTextSharp 5.5.12, and everything is working great, and it's so much simpler and much faster than the previous version, BUT, I think I've found a bug.

Specifically, when using a preexisting PDF with form fields on it and filling it out, if the field is marked as multi-line, then any preset or overridden text alignment is ignored and the text is always left aligned. If I un-mark the field as multi-line, then the preset alignment is honored.

Does anyone know of any way to work around this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in iText 7. I think it would be hard to work around the issue purely with your own code. The easiest way to be able to use justification for multiline fields while the bug is not fixed in iText 7 is probably fix the problem yourself and build the binaries from sources.

Take a look at the [PdfFormField](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/fields/PdfFormField.java) implementation. Here I've taken the latest development version, but feel free to base your fix on the `master` or any other version if you like.

The method of interest is `drawMultiLineTextAppearance`. You can see that `Canvas` instance is created and `Paragraph` instances are added to the `Canvas`. And justification is not mentioned anywhere! This is the place we should fix. First, we should convert the `justification` property of `PdfFormField` to the `TextAlignment` property of `layout` module that could later be used on a `Paragraph`:

```
Integer justification = getJustification();
if (justification == null) {
    justification = 0;
}
TextAlignment textAlignment = TextAlignment.LEFT;
if (justification == ALIGN_RIGHT) {
    textAlignment = TextAlignment.RIGHT;
} else if (justification == ALIGN_CENTER) {
    textAlignment = TextAlignment.CENTER;
}
```

And we are almost done! What is left is setting `TextAlignment` to the paragraph. Be sure to do it before the `Paragraph` is added to the `Canvas`:

```
// This line was already there
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(strings.get(index)).setFont(font).setFontSize(fontSize).setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0).setMultipliedLeading(1);
// This is the new line we are adding to fix the alignment problem
paragraph.setTextAlignment(textAlignment);
```

The complete piece of code:

```
// The block below was already there:
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(strings.get(index)).setFont(font).setFontSize(fontSize).setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0).setMultipliedLeading(1);
paragraph.setProperty(Property.FORCED_PLACEMENT, true);

// These are the new lines
Integer justification = getJustification();
if (justification == null) {
    justification = 0;
}
TextAlignment textAlignment = TextAlignment.LEFT;
if (justification == ALIGN_RIGHT) {
    textAlignment = TextAlignment.RIGHT;
} else if (justification == ALIGN_CENTER) {
    textAlignment = TextAlignment.CENTER;
}
paragraph.setTextAlignment(textAlignment);
```

That's it! What is left to be done is building the module with `mvn package` / `mvn install`. Please also refer to `BUILDING.md` for additional info on building.

The instructions are for the Java, but if you are using `.NET` version, then basically it's the same, only the build steps would be different.

iText is an open source product, so please don't be afraid of exploring the code and playing around.

Comment: This is the correct solution I believe, but I opted to just replace the field with a paragraph and it worked. I'll keep that solution until the bug gets fixed. Thanks for the help!